# grails: Passing a grails domain class as a function argument

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have two (5 in fact) domain classes, ClassA and ClassB and have to execute the same query on both

```
ClassA.where { a == b }.list()
```

and

```
ClassB.where { a == b }.list()
```

I want to write a service class to execute these queries passing the Class object instead of creating a service for each class. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338148/grails-find-domain-class-by-name)

```
def clazz = grailsApplication.getDomainClass(domainClass)
clazz.where { a == b }.list()
```

but I have an exception telling me that DefaultGrailsDomainClass dont have the 'where' method.

Is there other way to do this? something like "ClassA.grailsClass.where {}"

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of `getDomainClass` is a `GrailsDomainClass` / `DefaultGrailsDomainClass`. Call its `getClazz` method to get the Class it wraps:

```
def clazz = grailsApplication.getDomainClass(domainClass).clazz
clazz.where { a == b }.list()
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing with the findAll() where query, but it always returns all domain objects. The query is like this: ``clazz.findAll { prop == value }`` I wonder if this is a bug in Grails 2.1.1?