# how to get class from class-name

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a String *Person*, which is the name of a class `Person`.
Can I get the class `Person` from that string?. I need the class to call static methods of if.

In other words: is there an inverse to `Class.getName()`?

If that does not work at all, let me know. It is an answer too.

Comment: Have the answers below given you what you were looking for?

Answer (score 5):

`Class.forName` will work for a full name including the package.

If all you have is the bare name without a package, then there's no generic way but in the specific case of a Grails domain class (or other Grails artefact) you can [look it up via the `grailsApplication`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338307/592139).

Comment: I'm working in agrails environment, buthow can I get grailsApplication ?

Comment: I made it working now as generic as I want by getting grailsApplication by:'def grailsApplication = new Historie().domainClass.grailsApplication'

Comment: @user3647093 controllers have it automatically, services and domains can use autowiring (a class-level `def grailsApplication`), anywhere else you can retrieve it from `grails.util.Holders`

Answer (score 4):

```
class Person {
    static someMethod() {
        println 'Yep'
    }
}
```

If you know the name of the method that you want to invoke you can do something like this...

```
def className = 'Person'
def clz = Class.forName(className)
clz.someMethod()
```

If the method name is dynamic, you can do something like this...

```
def className = 'Person'
def methodName = 'someMethod'
def clz = Class.forName(className)
clz."$methodName"()
```

Comment: Calling the method directly on the clz object requires that method to be static as you're effectively calling Person.someMethod().

Comment: `"Calling the method directly on the clz object requires that method to be static as you're effectively calling Person.someMethod()"` @beechovsky That is correct.  The JVM doesn't allow you to invoke instance methods on a Class reference, because that wouldn't make sense.  The original question includes `"I need the class to call static methods of if."` so I demonstrated how to do that.

Comment: Ah - yup! I see now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a method: `Class.forName(<String>)` that should do the job You need. Mind the fact that You have to pass fully qualified class name (with package). See the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score -1):

You can get class using Class.forName() . Below code may help you

```
String type ="com.yourPackage.Person";
Class<Person> m = (Class<Person>) Class.forName(type);
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting that he invoke `newInstance`?

Comment: Also, the `(Object)` cast on the return value from `newInstance()` makes no sense.  Your `destClass` reference is declared with `Object`.  You can assign anything to an `Object` reference.  The cast doesn't do anything in this case.  The fact that you named the variable `destClass` makes me wonder if you thought that `newInstance()` returns the `java.lang.Class` object, as opposed to an instance of that class.