# Is there a way to create a relationship to an arbitraray domain object in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there a way to create an association to an arbitrary domain object in grails?

Something like

```
class ThingHolder {
    DomainObject thing;
}
```

and then

```
Book b=new Book(title: "Grails 101").save()
Author a=new Author(name: "Abe").save()

ThingHolder t1=new ThingHolder(thing:b).save()
ThingHolder t2=new ThingHolder(thing: a).save()
```

So that

```
ThingHolder.get(t1.id).thing  // will be a Book
```

and

```
ThingHolder.get(t2.id).thing  // will be an Author.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still looking for a grailsier way to do this, but this seems to get the job done.

```
class ThingHolder {
    static constraints = {
        thing bindable:true // required so 'thing' is bindable in default map constructor.
    }

    def grailsApplication;

    Object thing;

    String thingType;
    String thingId;

    void setThing(Object thing) {    //TODO: change Object to an interface
        this.thing=thing;
        this.thingType=thing.getClass().name
        this.thingId=thing.id;       //TODO: Grailsy way to get the id
    }

    def afterLoad() {
        def clazz=grailsApplication.getDomainClass(thingType).clazz
        thing=clazz.get(thingId);
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a Book and Author (that do not override the ID attribute for the domain object).

```
def thing1=new Author(name : "author").save(failOnError:true);
def thing2=new Book(title: "Some book").save(failOnError:true);

new ThingHolder(thing:thing1).save(failOnError:true)
new ThingHolder(thing:thing2).save(failOnError:true)

ThingHolder.list()*.thing.each { println it.thing }
```

I found some extremely useful tips in these two answers.

[How to make binding work in default constructor with transient values.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25761589/3617746)

[How to generate a domain object by string representation of class name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338307/3617746)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE (based on comment)**

Since you don't want to (or can't) extend another class in your domain model, this won't be possible using GORM.

**ORIGINAL Answer**

Yes, you can do this. It's called inheritance. In your case you would have a `Thing` which is the super class of both `Author` and `Book`.

Your domain model might look like this:

```
class Thing {
  // anything that is common among things should be here
}

class Author extends Thing {
  // anything that is specific about an author should be here
}

class Book extends Thing {
  // anything that is specific about a book should be here
}

class ThingHolder {
  Thing thing
}
```

Since both `Author` and `Book` extend `Thing` they are considered to be a `Thing` as well.

However, doing this without understanding inheritance and how Grails/GORM models the data in your database is short sighted. You should research those topics fully to make sure this is really what you want.

Comment: The goal is to be able to story any domain object.  I don't want to have every domain object in the system be stored in the Thing table, and don't want to have to set Table_per_hierarchy and cause outer joins all over the place.

Comment: Then the answer is no. You can't do that in GORM.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I was hoping for some magic that would create a Thing_holder table with columns ID, thing_discriminator, thing_id or something similar.